# Change the default path of Import Project in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to open an existing Maven project in Intellij. I am running intellij off of a development server because, directly running Intellij from windows would block me from accessing the databases, services etc.,

Now it opens /home/my-username by default in the open project popup. The problem is that /home is a nfs directory and it is the home folder of 3000+ developers and as soon as the popup opens, it starts indexing everything in that directory. I literally let it run for like an hour+ and it got no where. How do I set the default path of this popup so it only points to my home directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings and under Project Opening, set the Default directory.